# Problems accessing attributes of an object in a JSP

Tags: java, class, jsp, jsp-tags

I am currently working on a JAVA migration project in Webpshere and recently presented a problem to access the attributes of an object of type DECLARACION in session.

Before, I used this and was correct:

```html
<c:out value="${sessionScope.declaracion.id}" />
```

Now that line gives me error... I replaced with the following:

```html
<jsp:useBean id="declaracion" scope="request" class="ve.declaration.objetos.Declaracion"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:getProperty name="declaracion" property="id"/>
```

As this object has a type attribute CONTRIBUYENTE, the server throws me the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ve.declaracion.objetos.Contribuyente
```

If I use a class where all its attributes are standard data types, the jsp works OK. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the deployed war contains this `ve.declaracion.objetos.Contribuyente` class (in it's classes or in a jar)?

Comment: Thanks @LuiggiMendoza ... the "war" have this class, but do not know why you do not see... In the end, I created a library with all the class of package and "voila!"... Have a nice day!!! =D

Comment: Very strange, but glad to know that it worked in the end. It would be good to post your solution as an answer and mark it as the answer after 2 days.

Comment: Thank you. As I am new here, could you explain a little more about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a class named **ve.declaracion.objetos.Contribuyente** in classpath. The error is thrown because JVM cannot find the class.

Comment: Thanks @zawhtut .... I knew that this was the problem, but did not know how to fix it. In the end, I created a library with all the class of package and "voila!". What strikes me is that before migrating the application worked without this library .... not sure I got the most current.

Have a happy day!!! =D

Comment: Glad that you found the source of the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a library with all classes in the package **ve.declaration.objetos.***, deployed this library in the Websphere and it worked.

What strikes me is that before migrating the application to Websphere, it worked without this library .... not sure I got the code most current.